# Crypto Puzzle (All is not what it seems)

Tags: steganography, cryptic-clues

Follow all the clues to lead to a nice picture :D (Although you also lose)

> A code storage of western get waits by a meeting place. (6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cryptic is:**

> **GITHUB**:  A code storage (def); western get → GIT (say it with a drawl); meeting place → HUB

**Next part:**

> On OP's profile page is a reference to SilversApprentice.  Thanks to @Display name in TSL for pointing me to the github page for it **https://github.com/SilversApprentice** because I didn't realize that was a clickable link. D'oh!
>
>  The latest updated repo therein is **SilversApprentice.github.io**  which contains an HTML file **crypto.html**, which seems an obvious place to look.
>
>  The code therein references **https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS4ED.png**:
>  [image]

**Steganography part:**

> The BS4ED.png image isn't just image. @Display Name also pointed out there's something interesting tucked away at the end of the file. As it turns out, there's a RAR file here, with a file "png.txt" of length 27, tacked on the end of the PNG.
>
>   Extracting **png.txt** and reading it, we find:
>  **i.stack.imgur.com/hf8Cn.png**
>
>  So we go to that image next:
>  [image]

**And we've won!**
(And, yes, lost.)

Comment: I just lost the game.